# Sentry - how to log only exceptions, not logger

Tags: python, logging, sentry, raven

I want to use sentry for logging test exceptions. So I configured it:

```
# tests/__init__.py

from raven import Client
from raven.conf import setup_logging
from raven.handlers.logging import SentryHandler

client = Client(dsn='here goes dsn')
handler = SentryHandler(client, level=logging.ERROR)
setup_logging(handler)
```

When I run my test:

```
# tests/test_lolz.py

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def test_log():
    logger.warning('do not want to see this - warn')
    logger.error('do not want to see this - error')
    1 / 0  # yolo
```

I see both in sentry dashboard: logger error and exception

With logging level critical nothing appears.

So, is there a method to log only exceptions, but not regular logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sentry doesn't currently provide a way to say "only capture log events which have an exception attached", but you could write a `logging.Filter` for it. The Python docs are a bit sparse, but here's an example of a filter:

https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging-cookbook.html#using-filters-to-impart-contextual-information

You'd basically want to detect if the exception info is present on the entry, and if it is, return True (telling it to capture the entry).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I solved problem by doing two things: 1. nose plugin to log exceptions, 2. simple filter, just like you said. This solution works fine. Thanks!